# Pass along data using history.push - and re-render?

Tags: reactjs

I have a list of item components, that when clicked redirect to another view

```
            <Item
              key={id}
              onClick={() =>
                history.push({
                  pathname: '/logged-out/email-form',
                  state: {
                    action: data.name,
                  },
                })
              }
            />
```

redirect is working fine, and the view I need shows up after I click, but I cannot read the data I passed using history.push (`state.data.name`)

The next view:

```
export default withRouter(function FormCard(props) {
  let { location } = props;

  return (
    <div className="program-card text-center">


      <div className="heading mb-5 pt-2">
        {location.action ? location.action : 'Access your Options'}
      </div>

    </div>
  );
});
```

I am calling it a view, because I am not sure if this data, would only be visible if this view was extending a Component.

Do I need to re-render, to access the data, how would I do so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're accessing the property incorrectly.

You are using `location.action`, but you should be using `location.`*`state`*`.action`

According to the docs:

```
location - (object) The current location. May have the following properties:
  pathname - (string) The path of the URL
  search - (string) The URL query string
  hash - (string) The URL hash fragment
  state - (string) location-specific state that was provided to e.g. push(path, state) when this location was pushed onto the stack. Only available in browser and memory history.
```